# How to create related one-to-one object simultaneously when creating parent object in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `User` model that extend `AbstractUser` model inside an app that is called *core*. I use this model as `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in *settings.py*. I also have `UserProfile` model which has a one-to-one relationship with `User`
My goal is to create a UserProfile whenever a new User is created simultaneously.

```py
# file name: core/models.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

**The problem:** When I use shell to create a new user I get this error:

```
>>> bob = User.objects.create_user(email="bob@outlook.com", username="bob")

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'ModelBase'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <class 'core.models.User'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'core.models.User'>": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.
>>>
```

How should I solve this error?

To create `UserProfile` whenever a new `User` is created I use signals as shown below:

```py
# file name: core/signals.py

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from core.models import User, UserProfile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_userprofile(sender, **kwargs):
    try:
        UserProfile.objects.get(user=sender)
    except Exception:
        sender.userprofile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=sender)
```

I have registered this signal inside app config class:

```py
# file name: core/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'core'
    
    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
        
        return super().ready()
```

Comment: It is a bit "bizarre" to make both a custom user model and a profile. Usually if you make a custom user model, that will also contain fields that you would otherwise assign in a profile model. By doing this, you basically have the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using above method may not work the way you expected, because you do not add:

```
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

The `instance` and `created` is missing inside your `create_user_profile` function.

The `signals.py` file should be:

```
from django.conf import settings 
from django.db.models.signals import post_save 
from django.dispatch import receiver 
from core.models import UserProfile
  
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

@receiver(post_save, sender=User) 
 def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs): 
     if created: 
         UserProfe.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: So `created` is True if the object is being created for the first time. Am I right?

Comment: What `created` means is: Whenever the  `User` model is created, The `UserProfile` model will be created for that user.